# How to call a shared library function with multidimensional NumPy array

Tags: arrays, python-3.x, numpy, shared-libraries, ctypes

I have a NumPy array that I'd like to process in native code.

```
Hx = np.zeros([x_dim, y_dim, z_dim])
```

I have three implementations of the processing function:

1. Pure Python.

```
def update_eqn(x_dim,                \
               y_dim,                \
               z_dim,                \
               delta_x,       \
               delta_y,       \
               delta_z,       \
               Hx,   \
               Hy,   \
               Hz,   \
               Ex,   \
               Ey,   \
               Ez,   \
               Chxh, \
               Chxe, \
               Chyh, \
               Chye, \
               Chzh, \
               Chze, \
               Cexe, \
               Cexh, \
               Ceye, \
               Ceyh, \
               Ceze, \
               Cezh):

    for i in range(x_dim):
        for j in range(y_dim-1):
            for k in range(z_dim-1):
                Hx[i][j][k] = Chxh[i][j][k] * Hx[i][j][k] + \
                              Chxe[i][j][k] * ( ( (1 / delta_z) * (Ey[i][j][k+1] - Ey[i][j][k]) ) - \
                                              ( ( (1 / delta_y) * (Ez[i][j+1][k] - Ez[i][j][k]) ) ) )
```

2. A Cython implementation:

```
def update_eqn(x_dim,                \
               y_dim,                \
               z_dim,                \
               double delta_x,       \
               double delta_y,       \
               double delta_z,       \
               double[:, :, :] Hx,   \
               double[:, :, :] Hy,   \
               double[:, :, :] Hz,   \
               double[:, :, :] Ex,   \
               double[:, :, :] Ey,   \
               double[:, :, :] Ez,   \
               double[:, :, :] Chxh, \
               double[:, :, :] Chxe, \
               double[:, :, :] Chyh, \
               double[:, :, :] Chye, \
               double[:, :, :] Chzh, \
               double[:, :, :] Chze, \
               double[:, :, :] Cexe, \
               double[:, :, :] Cexh, \
               double[:, :, :] Ceye, \
               double[:, :, :] Ceyh, \
               double[:, :, :] Ceze, \
               double[:, :, :] Cezh):

    cdef int i, j, k
    cdef int x_dim_c = x_dim
    cdef int y_dim_c = y_dim
    cdef int z_dim_c = z_dim

    cdef double Ex_past
    cdef double Ey_past
    cdef double Ez_past
    cdef double Ex_std
    cdef double Ey_std
    cdef double Ez_std
    cdef double curl_H_x
    cdef double curl_H_y
    cdef double curl_H_z

    for i in range(x_dim_c):
        for j in range(y_dim_c-1):
            for k in range(z_dim_c-1):
                Hx[i][j][k] = Chxh[i][j][k] * Hx[i][j][k] + \
                              Chxe[i][j][k] * ( ( (1 / delta_z) * (Ey[i][j][k+1] - Ey[i][j][k]) ) - \
                                              ( ( (1 / delta_y) * (Ez[i][j+1][k] - Ez[i][j][k]) ) ) )
```

3. A C implementation:

```
void update_eqn(int    x_dim,        \
                int    y_dim,        \
                int    z_dim,        \
                double delta_x,      \
                double delta_y,      \
                double delta_z,      \
                double *Hx,        \
                double *Hy,        \
                double *Hz,        \
                double *Ex,        \
                double *Ey,        \
                double *Ez,        \
                double *Chxh,      \
                double *Chxe,      \
                double *Chyh,      \
                double *Chye,      \
                double *Chzh,      \
                double *Chze,      \
                double *Cexe,      \
                double *Cexh,      \
                double *Ceye,      \
                double *Ceyh,      \
                double *Ceze,      \
                double *Cezh) {

  int map;
  int map1;
  int map2;

  for (int i=0; i<x_dim; i++) {
    for(int j=0; j<y_dim-1; j++) {
      for(int k=0; k<z_dim-1; k++) {

        //[i][j][k]
        map = ( i * (y_dim * z_dim) ) + ( j * z_dim ) + k;

        //[i][j][k+1]
        map1 = map + 1;

        //[i][j+1][k]
        map2 = map + z_dim;

        Hx[map] = Chxh[map] * Hx[map] +                                    \
                  Chxe[map] * ( ( (1 / delta_z) * (Ey[map1] - Ey[map]) ) - \
                              ( ( (1 / delta_y) * (Ez[map2] - Ez[map]) ) ) );
      }
    }
  }

}
```

The C function is called using Python's ctypes library as follows:

```
my_functions.update_eqn(x_dim,                           \
                        y_dim,                           \
                        z_dim,                           \
                        c_double(delta_x),               \
                        c_double(delta_y),               \
                        c_double(delta_z),               \
                        c_void_p(Hx.ctypes.data),        \
                        c_void_p(Hy.ctypes.data),        \
                        c_void_p(Hz.ctypes.data),        \
                        c_void_p(Ex.ctypes.data),        \
                        c_void_p(Ey.ctypes.data),        \
                        c_void_p(Ez.ctypes.data),        \
                        c_void_p(Chxh.ctypes.data),      \
                        c_void_p(Chxe.ctypes.data),      \
                        c_void_p(Chyh.ctypes.data),      \
                        c_void_p(Chye.ctypes.data),      \
                        c_void_p(Chzh.ctypes.data),      \
                        c_void_p(Chze.ctypes.data),      \
                        c_void_p(Cexe.ctypes.data),      \
                        c_void_p(Cexh.ctypes.data),      \
                        c_void_p(Ceye.ctypes.data),      \
                        c_void_p(Ceyh.ctypes.data),      \
                        c_void_p(Ceze.ctypes.data),      \
                        c_void_p(Cezh.ctypes.data))
```

I have two questions about this:

1. Is the approach in the C implementation that I am taking here with the multidimensional NumPy array correct? Is it safe and correct to handle it the way that I am? Is there a better way of doing this?
2. The performance of the C function isn't as good as the Cython implementation. For example, observed run times are as follows:

- Pure Python = 1.6436338424682617
- Cython      = 0.0013880729675292969
- C Function  = 0.0030319690704345703

This was with iteration counts of:

```
x_dim   = 30
y_dim   = 500
z_dim   = 22
```

So, I'm wondering why my C function is slower than Cython? Is it due to the way that I'm trying to access the array with the 'map' variables, essentially flattening the structure to 1D?

It feels like it should be possible to improve the C implementation to achieve performance parity with Cython, but I don't know how to do that. I'd like use C as these computations can be done in parallel and eventually I'd like to migrate the code to use the GPU. For reference, this function is called 1000s of times during a simulation and therefore speed is critical.

I am not an expert in this area by any means. Any suggestions or improvements that anyone can recommend here would be appreciated.

Comment: I guess for the C-version the compiler flags are to check first. You also have to check if the arrays are c-contiguous before calling into C (`np.ascontiguousarray()` otherwise you can get wrong results). For the Cython version it can be beneficial to limit the function for c-contiguous arrays eg. `double[:, :, ::1] Cezh`. Another approach would be Numba (I got 600µs, there). If you don't have the data already on the GPU, I think copying around the arrays will take longer than the calculation on the CPU.